# rake assets:precompile attempting to connect to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm attempting to debug why my application is attempting to connect to my database when I run `rake assets:precompile --trace`.

I'm probably missing something in the stack trace...anyone see the pertinent line?

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: The InstanceMethods module inside ActiveSupport::Concern will be no longer included automatically. Please define instance methods directly in ActionController::Base instead. (called from <top (required)> at /Users/Kyle/Desktop/skateparks-web/config/application.rb:4)
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
DEPRECATION WARNING: The InstanceMethods module inside ActiveSupport::Concern will be no longer included automatically. Please define instance methods directly in ActionController::Base instead. (called from <top (required)> at /Users/Kyle/Desktop/skateparks-web/config/application.rb:4)
** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile:all
** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
FATAL:  database "skateparks_production" does not exist
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1161:in `initialize'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1161:in `new'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1161:in `connect'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:316:in `initialize'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:27:in `new'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:27:in `postgresql_connection'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:277:in `new_connection'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:287:in `checkout_new_connection'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:235:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:230:in `loop'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:230:in `block in checkout'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:229:in `checkout'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:95:in `connection'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:374:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:168:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:142:in `connection'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:308:in `clear_cache!'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:418:in `_run__2041913228368879189__prepare__1991931652306887621__callbacks'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:74:in `prepare!'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:48:in `prepare!'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:48:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/Users/Kyle/Desktop/skateparks-web/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:292:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:89:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:176:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:157:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:56:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in `invoke_task'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `each'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `block in top_level'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:84:in `top_level'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:62:in `block in run'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `run'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/bin/rake:32:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => environment
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/Users/Kyle/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bi...]
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:53:in `block in create_shell_runner'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `call'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `sh'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:36:in `sh'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:78:in `ruby'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:36:in `ruby'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:9:in `ruby_rake_task'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:17:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:25:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in `invoke_task'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `each'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `block in top_level'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:84:in `top_level'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:62:in `block in run'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `run'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/rake-0.9.2/bin/rake:32:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`rake assets:precompile` initializes your app by default, which includes connection to the database.

Inside `config/application.rb` you can add this, but see the link below for warnings about it:

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

[Rails Guide on Precompiling Assets](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets)

Comment: The link above goes to the latest docs.. (and the warning was not there). For Rails 3.2 version of docs with the warning, go here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets

Comment: @KARASZIIstván this appears to be working on Rails 4.2.4. Think its been fixed.

Comment: @karaszi-istván I posted a solution for Rails 4.2.1. After tested a lot of solutions, finally I solved

Answer (score 12):

I had that same problem. After updating Sprockets to version 3, whenever I tried to precompile the assets locally (development), however using the settings of the production environment, I had this error:

> rake aborted!
>   Gem::LoadError: Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).

Because in my local (development) I use MySQL and in the server (production), I use Postgres.

The answer marked as resolved does not work for me, because `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile` is not available in `Rails 4.2.1`.

To solve, I followed 3 simple steps:

1. In your Gemfile, add: `gem "activerecord-nulldb-adapter"`
2. In `database.yml`, change the adapter as follow:

   ```
   production:
     adapter: <%= ENV['DB_ADAPTER'] ||= 'postgresql' %>
   ```
3. To compile your production assets locally. run in your terminal

   ```
   DB_ADAPTER=nulldb RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
   ```

This solutions solved to me and I sawyed [here](http://blog.zeit.io/use-a-fake-db-adapter-to-play-nice-with-rails-assets-precompilation/).

Comment: The `adapter` value should read: `adapter: <%= ENV['DB_ADAPTER'] || 'postgresql' %>`, with `||` not `||=`.

Comment: Also, I thought `nulldb` sounded like a good solution, but unfortunately it still does not support Postgres extensions such as `uuid`.

Comment: I use
`DATABASE_URL=nulldb:fake bundle exec rails assets:precompile` (you should append `gem 'activerecord-nulldb-adapter'` to `Gemfile`, see https://github.com/nulldb/nulldb )

Answer (score 12):

Newer versions of Rails do not load the database during asset precompile. However, initializers will often cause it to load. This can be frustrating to debug, because the error omits the stack trace.

```
./bin/rails assets:precompile
(in ~/src/nautilus)
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: FATAL:  database "your_app_development" does not exist
bundler: failed to load command: rake (~/src/your_app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/bin/rake)
NoMethodError: undefined method `reject' for nil:NilClass
```

*The less than helpful error.*

---

So, how do we figure out where the problem is?

Move *all* the initializers out of `config/initializers` then run `./bin/rails assets:precompile`.

If it works, great, you know the problem is in one of those files.

Move them back one by one till you find the offending file(s).

---

Now that the problem was found, how do we fix it?

Then when I find an initialilzer that has a problem I wrap it with the following check:

```
unless ARGV.include? "assets:precompile"
  # ...
end
```

I prefer this over the nulldb because it reduces the number of dependencies I have to maintain in the app.

Answer (score 6):

If it makes sense in your situation, you can choose against which environment `assets:precompile` should work, with the following command:

```
rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=development RAILS_GROUPS=assets
```

This make sense for my deployment because usually:

1. I make rake to generates assets on my development machine (because the memory of my vps is somehow limited)
2. I zip all the application with the assets generated in public/assets
3. I transfer the zip to the vps ans unzip the package there

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! This is also perfect when using Cells 4 with bundled assets. Cells adds directories to the AP via a railtie, but needs the cell class files to be loaded, and turning off initialize_on_precompile breaks this.

Answer (score 2):

Check your configuration files (in all environments). If for example

```
rake assets:precompile
```

works in development, but you are having issues in production

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

then you most likely have a reference to active record in your **/config/environments/production.rb**

```
config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
```

In order to avoid that altogether if you are planning on not taking advantage of active record or employing a NoSQL such as mongo, you may wish to initialize your new app as follows:

```
rails new myApp --skip-active-record
```

which is equivalent to -O (capital O) as far as I am concerned.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this won't work for all cases but I was able to avoid Rails attempting to connect to the database on the `rake assets:*` tasks by surrounding the code in some places with the snippet below on the `/config/routes.rb`:

```
unless defined?(::Rake::SprocketsTask)
  devise_for ...
    #...
  end

  devise_scope ...
    #...
  end
end
```

Sometimes code which depends on external services or environment variables will get loaded because of code on the initializer files which are not required for assets to be precompiled.

I've recently faced a similar issue and the responses above didn't work for me. I've found the file on `config/initializers/` that was causing the issue and wrapped it with the following code:

```
unless defined?(::Rake::SprocketsTask)
  #...
end
```

The snippet above will skip the code within it when running `rake assets:precompile` or others like `rake assets:clean` as well.

Hopefully this will help others in the future!