# rake assets:precompile doesn't work with PostgreSql

Tags: postgresql, rake, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to deploy a Rails 3.2.3 App that uses Postgres. I got the deploy itself working via Capistrano, also the db migrations worked. But now I'm stuck precompiling the assets:

```
deploy:MyAPP/current$ bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby /home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile:all
** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
** Execute tmp:cache:clear
** Execute assets:precompile:primary
** Invoke assets:precompile:nondigest (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
FATAL:  role "deploy" does not exist
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1194:in `initialize'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1194:in `new'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1194:in `connect'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:329:in `initialize'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `new'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `postgresql_connection'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:303:in `new_connection'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:313:in `checkout_new_connection'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:237:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:232:in `loop'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:232:in `block in checkout'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:229:in `checkout'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:95:in `connection'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:398:in `retrieve_connection'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:168:in `retrieve_connection'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:142:in `connection'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:308:in `clear_cache!'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:418:in `_run__1909267555841955845__prepare__3200542818861587462__callbacks'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:74:in `prepare!'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:48:in `prepare!'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:47:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/releases/20120503154931/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:292:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:93:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:176:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:157:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => environment
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/b...]
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:53:in `block in create_shell_runner'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `call'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `sh'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:39:in `sh'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:80:in `ruby'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:39:in `ruby'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:12:in `ruby_rake_task'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:21:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/home/deploy/www/MyApp/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
```

For some reason it tries to login to Postgres as the systemuser "deploy", but I have absolutely no idea why – I have never experienced that issue with MySql...

Does anybody have an idea?

Cheers, CS

Comment: Are you accessing your models in your CSS or JS files?

Comment: No, in fact it's just the default scaffold.css.scss file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rake initializes the whole rails stack and the postgres adapter seems to test the connection on startup. Since there are no credentials for that case, rake fails.

To prevent rake from doing so, I had to put that in my `config/application.rb`:

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

That works for me!

Found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8997640/727341).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't supply any other username by default PostgreSQL will use the operating-system username (when connections are local the the one machine). That's presumably why it's using "deploy".

Where/how you need to set the database name so it gets picked up I can't say I'm afraid.