# How to avoid rake assets:precompile to load the entire application on rails 4.2.11?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rake

I have a dynamic route file which defines constraints using the database.

```
XXX::Engine.routes.draw do
  scope '(:locale)', locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join('|')}/ do
    get "/:intent-:currency", to: 'offers#index', constraints: { intent: /deposit|withdraw/, currency: load_from_database }
  end
end
```

I must load the constraint from database as the expression is more complex than this. I simplified to make my point.

`rake assets:precompile` loads the entire application and there is no database yet on my CI yet. If I try to run `rake db:create && rake db:migrate` it will still try to load the app leaving me stuck as I need the database for the dynamic routes, but I can't migrate the database as it loads the app

I need to find a way to avoid `rake assets:precompile` to not load the entire app or at least avoid database connection while it does the precompilation

NullDb adapter seems to be working, but there should be another way as I don't wanna add more gems to my project

I should be able to run `rake assets:precompile` without loading the application (the routes.rb file is loaded and it depends on the databse so it will fail as on my pipeline I need the precompilation before)

Answer (score 1):

NullDb gem seemed tempting but I prefer to avoid adding gems to my projects

This worked for me. Answering my own question after pulling my hair for a day

```
XXX::Engine.routes.draw do
  scope '(:locale)', locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join('|')}/ do
    get "/:intent-:currency", to: 'offers#index', constraints: { intent: /deposit|withdraw/, currency: load_from_database } unless defined?(::Rake::SprocketsTask)
  end
end
```

Comment: I've found a similar solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65125384/1463744 hope it helps!